# C# Оптимизация кода перебора слов в тексте

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Я перебираю весь текст и делаю словарь, в котором видно, какие слова идут перед каждым словом в тексте. То есть например по тексту "один два три один четыре три" будет сформирован словарь:

- один   --  два, четыре
- два    --  три
- три    --  один
- четыре --  три

Код реализации:

```
  public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

  private List<string> list = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '-', '%', '(', ')' }).ToList();

  public void TranslateToDict()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; ++i)
            {

                try
                {
                    dict.Add(list[i], new List<string>());
                    dict[list[i]].Add(list[i + 1]);
                }
                catch
                {
                    dict[list[i]].Add(list[i + 1]);
                }
            }


        }
```

Текст большой и время выполнения этого кода слишком велико(несколько минут)

Comment: Вопрос. в списке слов, следующих за каждым (который привязан к каждому слову), значения - уникальные? Потому что если уникальные, то 1) должен быть не  Dictionary<string, List<string>>, а Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>> 2) это будет гораздо оптимальнее, по крайней мере, по памяти. А может, и скорость удастся "подтянуть"

Comment: Нет, значения могут многократно повторяться, поэтому я и использовал List и try-catch(но это было большой ошибкой, хоть код и работал)

Comment: Понял... похоже на обучение "бредогенератора" :-)

Comment: Все именно так)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что try у вас много лишней работы делает:

```
  public void TranslateToDict()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                string current = list[i];
                string next = list[i + 1];
                
                if (dict.ContainsKey(current)){
                    dict[current].Add(next);
                }
                else {
                    dict.Add(current, new List<string>() { next });
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Очень красиво. Еще есть, оказывается, у dictionary метод TryAdd.

Comment: Какая круть! Это ж сколько лишней работы происходит во время каждого catch, что оптимизация заметна на глаз!