# Вероятность появления символа в тексте С#

Tags: c#

Я новичок, пытался сделать програмку, суть которой посчитать количество символов в тексте, вроде работает. Теперь нужно сделать так чтобы еще показывалась вероятность появления символов.

К примеру есть текст "ЗАВТРА БУДЕТ ДОЖДЬ", вероятность появления буквы "Д" = 3/18, так как символов всего 18, включая пробелы, а буква повторяется трижды. Вот я что-то затрудняюсь, как мне это сюда впихнуть. Возможно кто знает, как это сделать лучше.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            double chars = richTextBox1.Text.Length;
            string TEXT = richTextBox1.Text;//текст
            string text = TEXT.ToLower();//в маленкие символы
            
            string AlreadyDone = "";
            string[,] Result = new string[text.Length, 2];
            
            
            int i = 0, l = 0;
            foreach (char ch in text)
            {
                i = 0;
                foreach (char c in text)
                {
                    if (ch == c) i++;
                }
                
                if (AlreadyDone.Contains(ch) != true)
                {
                    Result[l, 0] = ch.ToString();//символ
                    Result[l, 1] = i.ToString(); //кол-во символов
                   
                    AlreadyDone += ch; 
                    l++;
                }
            }
            for (int s = 0; s < AlreadyDone.Length; s++)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(Result[s, 0] + "  повторяется " + Result[s, 1] + " раз ");
            }
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема поделить `result[s, 1]` на `chars`? Вообще то что у вас сделано, очень легко решается через словарь.

Comment: 1) согласен с aepot, что реализация достаточно странная, но считаю, что надо оставить ваше решение, оно уникальное, нет смысла делать стандартно, скажут что списали (вы же не списали, а сами сделали?). 2) подумайте сами, как зная сколько раз встречается символ (скажем, Д встречается 3 раза), получить его вероятность (3/18)

Comment: @aepot я попатался так делать перед тем как постить вопрос, у меня не получаеться разделить `string Result` на `chars` возможно ето можно как то зделать но я не знаю)

Comment: Уже вопрос изчерпан наше как конвертировать string)

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите аналогичную задачу. Только ней собирается список, а вам нужно суммировать [C# Оптимизация кода перебора слов в тексте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1396008/c-%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5/1396012#1396012)